# jQuery: remove tags but keep content?

Tags: jquery

I know this question has been asked before but mine is slightly different.

I have a html that looks like this:

```
[caption id="attachment_12543" align="aligncentre" width="583"]<img class="wp-image-12543 size-full" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/11307931562035142140" alt="" width="583" height="400">[/caption]
```

I need to remove the `caption` tags and just keep its content (images and texts).

I tried this code but it doesn't do anything.

```
$("caption").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });
```

```js
$("caption").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

[caption id="attachment_12543" align="aligncentre" width="583"]<img class="wp-image-12543 size-full" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/11307931562035142140" alt="" width="583" height="400">[/caption]
```

could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[caption]` isn't a valid element so jQuery won't do anything when you try to use normal tag selector syntax

Comment: @j08691, yes, I realise that. but the content is coming from a MYSQL database which is for a wordpress website and it has these strange tags!

Comment: Does each caption have it's own container? Can you also show us the parent container that wraps them all, if any.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen, the parent container is just a simple <div>...</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version uses a regex to remove only the opening and closing caption tags

```js
$('div').html(function(){
  var html = this.innerHTML;
  
  html = html.replace(/(\[caption [^\]]+\])/, '');
  html = html.replace(/(\[\/caption\])/, '');

  return html;
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Other stuff
[caption id="attachment_12543" align="aligncentre" width="583"]
<img class="wp-image-12543 size-full" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/11307931562035142140" alt="" width="583" height="400">
I got some text yo!!!
[/caption]
Even more stuff
</div>
```

Comment: that only works for images. what about when there are texts in there as well? something like this: [caption id="attachment_12543" align="aligncentre" width="583"]
<img class="wp-image-12543 size-full" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/11307931562035142140" alt="" width="583" height="400">helooooooooo asjdha djajsdh ajsdhajsdhas ajsdhasd ajsdh jasdjasdhjasdhjash dajsdhjasd hjashjashdjhsa asasd asdasdasd asdasd asdasdasdas
[/caption]

Comment: Yes. all I need the caption part gone but keep its content the way that you demonstrated in your answer.

Comment: with your edited code, it also includes the texts as it should BUT it will remove everything else from within parent DIV container. So, if the DIV container has other children and elements, they get removed.

Comment: Updated to remove only the tags. @RoozFar